# how to automatically reisize the controls on the form?

Tags: vb.net

i made my application in 1366 x 768 resolution and i want to be flexible when i install it in a unit with 1028 x 600 resolution it will automatically resizes the controls to fit in the screen. is it that possible in vb.net ?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [`Control.Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You will need to do some tests to find the correct way to use this in your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set following properties in your form

```
Me.AutoSize = True 
Me.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
```

For more details take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)